# covert to pandas dataframe from loop print statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following loop I want to convert it to the data frame.I have seen a [old related-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60085872/how-can-i-convert-results-from-a-for-loop-print-statement-to-pandas-dataframe). But It does not address my problem

```
closest_n = 10
for query, query_embedding in zip(queries, query_embeddings):
    distances = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist([query_embedding], corpus_embeddings, "cosine")[0]
    results = zip(range(len(distances)), distances)
    results = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x[1])

for idx, distance in results[0:closest_n]:
    print("Score:   ", "(Score: %.4f)" % (1-distance) , "\n" )
    print("content:   ", corpus[idx].strip(), "\n" )
    row_di = dfc2.loc[dfc2.index== corpus[idx]].to_dict()
    print("date:  " , row_di["date"][corpus[idx]] , "\n")
    print("Title:  " , row_di["title"][corpus[idx]] , "\n")
    print("-------------------------------------------")
```

My attempt

```
d = []  
for idx, distance in results[0:closest_n]:
  d.append(
      {'score':(1-distance),
       'paragraph':corpus[idx].strip(),
       #'row_dic' : dfc2.loc[dfc2.index== corpus[idx]].to_dict()
          
      }
  )
    
  ad = pd.DataFrame(d)
  ad.head(2)
```

[image]

How to put the following lines of codes into the loop to make the data frame. We get two columns one `data` another `title` from `row_di`.

```
row_di = dfc2.loc[dfc2.index== corpus[idx]].to_dict()
print("date:  " , row_di["date"][corpus[idx]] , "\n")
print("Title:  " , row_di["title"][corpus[idx]] , "\n")
```

Comment: Can you show the list(s). You don't need the for loop IMO

Comment: Thanks, Sid, I have now added another chunk of the code. I hope it will be more clear now. Please let me know.